# Change image color outside a quadrilateral

Tags: matlab, function

I have positions of 4 points in RGB image, those 4 points give a quadrilateral shape. the question is how to make outside this quadrilateral black in the image in MATLAB??? Is there any Matlab function that can do this job???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `poly2mask` to draw a mask with given points. refer to the official reference http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html for usage information. Since you have the positions of vertices and size of image, it is quite easy to generate the mask matrix.

Then, optionally, write a new RGB image matrix of the same size as the one to be edited. Fill it with all black. You can skip this step as black pixels can be generated just-in-time.

Lastly create a new RGB image with the following rules. For each pixel, if the point is masked then it is black. Otherwise it is equal to the original image.

reference - [how to sketch a polygon in a matrix or binary image in order to use image processing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/786375/3839249)